# In component data is fetched only when i make some changes in it

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am trying to add markers on map, using a view and component
In view where i call an api and then i pass that data to component using v:bind but console.log in that component shows an empty array, when i make some changes in that component the page reloads and data is fetched following is my code in view and then component.

```js
//Script for View
<script>
import Maps from '../components/Maps.vue';
import LoadingOverlay from '../components/loading.vue';
import MessageHelper from '../helpers/messageHelper';
import RepositoryFactory from '../repositories/RepositoryFactory';

const Catalogs = RepositoryFactory.get('catalogs');
export default {
  components: {
    Maps,
    LoadingOverlay,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      zones_and_locations: [],
      loadingConfig: {
        isLoading: true,
        cancellable: true,
        onCancelMessage: this.onCancelMessage(),
        isFullPage: true,
      },
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchPlacesData();
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchPlacesData() {
      const { data } = await Catalogs.getZoneLocations();
      if (data.output === null) {
        this.nullDataException();
      } else {
        const places = [];
        data.output.forEach((value, index) => {
          places.push(value);
        });
        this.zones_and_locations = places;
        this.loadingConfig.isLoading = false;
      }
    },
    onCancelMessage() {
      return MessageHelper.getLoadingCancelMessage();
    },
    nullDataException() {
      this.exceptionMessage = 'Data from API is not available.';
      console.log(this.exceptionMessage);
    },
  },
};
</script>
//Script For Map.vue
<script>
import MarkerClusterer from '@google/markerclusterer';
import GoogleMapsHelper from '../helpers/GoogleMapsHelper';

export default {
  name: 'GoogleMap',
  props: ['zones_and_locations'],
  data() {
    return {
      country: '',
      markers: [],
      map: '',
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.loadGoogleMaps();
  },
  methods: {
    markerClusterer(map, markers) {
      return new MarkerClusterer(
        map,
        markers,
        { imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m' },
      );
    },
    async loadGoogleMaps() {
      try {
        const google = await GoogleMapsHelper();
        const geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 7,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          fullscreenControl: false,
        });
        geoCoder.geocode({ address: 'Singapore' }, (results, status) => {
          if (status !== 'OK' || !results[0]) {
            throw new Error(status);
          }
          // set Center of Map
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
        });
        this.map = map;
        let zones = [];
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.zones_and_locations, child => {
          var obj = {
            lat: parseFloat(child.lat),
            lng: parseFloat(child.lng),
          }
          var position = {
            position: obj,
          };
          zones.push(position);
        });
        if (zones.length > 0) {
          const markers = zones.map(x => new google.maps.Marker({ ...x, map }));
          this.markerClusterer(map, markers);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
//Template for View
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- START::Loading Overlay -->
    <LoadingOverlay
            v-bind:loadingConfig="loadingConfig">
    </LoadingOverlay><!-- END::Loading Overlay -->
  <Maps v-bind:zones_and_locations="zones_and_locations"
  ></Maps>
  </div>
</template>
//Template for Component
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="map" class="google-map"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: please, add some code replicating the issue in order to let us understand how we can help you :)

Comment: just added code

Comment: can you please also add the template of the components?

Comment: added in code just now

Comment: `fetchPlacesData` is the only place were `zones_and_locations` is changed: can you point out when and where `fetchPlacesData` function is called?

Comment: fetchplaces data is called when i load my page, it returns the data from api and that is printed in console with no issues, i store it to zones_and_locations and pass it to component using v:bind but the data is empty there.

Comment: please, add the entire code showing the flow, better if divided into main app and map component

Comment: added code of both with comments i was unable to seperate them as its my first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data from the parent component are loaded asynchronously, so the `created` lifecycle hook inside the component is executed *before* the actual data comes, when they're still set as an empty array and are not reactive to change.

You can fix this by setting a `watch` inside the component, like this:

```js
methods: {
  ...
},
watch: {
  zones_and_locations (newVal, oldVal) {
    this.loadGoogleMaps();
  }
}
```

orelse you can set a reference to the child component and invoke its method when data comes:

```html
  <!-- main view -->
  <Maps
    v-bind:zones_and_locations="zones_and_locations"
    ref="myMap"
  ></Maps>
```

```js
    async fetchPlacesData() {
      const { data } = await Catalogs.getZoneLocations();
      if (data.output === null) {
        this.nullDataException();
      } else {
        const places = [];
        data.output.forEach((value, index) => {
          places.push(value);
        });
        this.zones_and_locations = places;
        // using $refs
        this.$refs.myMap.loadGoogleMaps();
        this.loadingConfig.isLoading = false;
      }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks will try your method too, i solved this by re-rendering the component through key